# Generalized method of moments (GMM): testing equality of parameters across subsamples

Tags: hypothesis-testing, generalized-moments, subsampling

I estimate parameters of a panel data model with GMM using Stata. I specify the variance-covariance matrix assuming that the observations are correlated in the same period of time (`vce(cluster year)`). I estimate them using the observations for two subsamples (they don't cross).

- How can I test if these estimates for the same parameter are equal or not for these two subsamples?
- More importantly, how can I get the covariance of these estimates?